# Excel VBA Update Cells In Range

Tags: excel, vba

What is the best method to update all cells in a range?  I specify the desired range to cycle through, but I can only update the current and previous cell from where my cursor is.

```
Sub updateValues()

    Dim cell As Range
    
    For Each cell In Range("C1:C20")

        If ActiveCell.Value = ActiveCell.Offset(-1, 0) Then
        
        ActiveCell.Offset(-1, 0).Value = ActiveCell.Offset(-1, 0).Value + " Start"
            
        ActiveCell.Value = ActiveCell.Value + " Stop"
        
        End If
    
    Next cell
    
End Sub
```

I am trying to update ~400k records in Excel from this:

[image]

To this, but it's only updating the active cell and its previous:

[image]

I've tried various implementations from what I've seen online, but it never seems to loop for some reason.  Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: The problem is you're using `ActiveCell` instead of `cell`. Though for 400k records, this approach will be extremely slow. Better to use a `Variant` array.

Comment: @BigBen - doesn't it need to cycle through each active cell?  I tried changing all instances from ActiveCell to a cell property instead, but it errors out going into debug mode.  Can you please provide a general code example of how you mean it should be implemented?

Comment: `For Each cell In Range("C1:C20")` should be `For Each cell In Range("C2:C20")` since you are `Offset`ting 1 row up in the loop.

Comment: It still has the same results when I change the value to anything other than "C1", such as C2 or C3 to account for the header.  It seems like the for each loop just isn't iterating as it should and stops after the first iteration is complete.

Comment: Your misunderstanding is that `For Each cell In Range("C1:C20")` doesn't make any cell active.. a cell doesn't need to be active. Activating a cell is what a human does. Code doesn't need to do that. `ActiveCell` has nothing to do with your loop.

Comment: I see what you mean.  I updated it again to cell.Value and it's not throwing a debug issue this time, but actually working.  Thank you for the help!

Comment: I'd change the `+` in these lines to `&`:   `ActiveCell.Value + " Stop"`.  If `ActiveCell` contains "Running operations " then it works, if it contains a number it will throw a Type mismatch error as you can't add text to a number.  Probably won't occur in this scenario, but is a habit worth breaking.

Answer (score 0):

Without VBA you could make a new column with just "1" and "2".

1. Copy 1 and 2, paste it "from the bottom and up"
2. Hide 2, replace all vissible with start.
3. Hide 1, replace all vissible with stop.

I think it should work even if its a big file.

[image]

Br
John

Comment: I won't be able to do that because there are one-offs that won't have a matching value, so I need to script through it with conditions.